# Setting name = NULL on NOT NULL field

Tags: sql, null

I just can't figure out how is this happening, maybe you guys can help me!

I have an user table with "name NOT NULL".

This give me an error.

```
INSERT INTO `user` (name) values (NULL);`
```

This works, and set name to `''`.

```
UPDATE `user` SET name=NULL WHERE id = '1'
```

Why I can update it? Why its not showing me the same error when I tried to insert?

Comment: Are you sure the UPDATE statement is actually updating a record?  Does SELECT * from `user` where name IS NULL return any data?

Comment: what sql product are you using? MySQL? MS SQL Server? something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using MySQL, this is a bug that is not a bug. 
http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=33699
It was fixed, and then the fix was reverted.

> This change was reverted, because the original report was determined
>   not to be a bug: Assigning NULL to a NOT NULL column in an UPDATE
>   statement should produce an error only in strict SQL mode and set the
>   column to the implicit default with a warning otherwise, which was the
>   original behavior.

Comment: That was freaking me out! So, the solution for that would be change to strict mode?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are starting from an empty table, when you try to insert a user with a null name and it gives you an error, the table is still empty. The update command will not give you an error, but because there is not a row with an id of 1, so no rows have been changed. It should give you an error if you do the following:

```
INSERT INTO user (id, name) VALUES (1, "blah")
UPDATE user SET name=NULL WHERE id=1
```

Edit:
Ah... you updated your question while I was writing my answer.
In that case, do you have an empty string as the default for the name column? It could be using that.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot update it. You can only execute query if it couldn't find out any matches by WHERE statement. In that case you didn't get an error, because query doesn't try to update any row.